# Why are solvmanifolds of importance?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, solvable-groups

I'm not sure if this belongs in physics stackexchange but I am curious as to why we study solvmanifolds. Of course there are instances with Einstein solvmanifolds and solvmanifolds as a subset of nilmanifold theory, but im not sure what importance solvmanifolds carry. thank you!

Comment: Bruh, this is math stackexchange, this DEFINITELY belongs here. Don’t know what they are btw, sorry

Comment: If I recall correctly, they are used to study dynamic systems (which don't have to physics related though).

Comment: The number of researchers who study solvmanifolds is actually quite small, even among geometers. Say, in 3-dimensional geometry/topology community, most effort is in the direction of hyperbolic manifolds, not solvmanifolds. In general many questions about homogeneous Riemannian manifolds are easier than ones about general manifolds. So, a possible answer is along the lines of  the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streetlight_effect.

Comment: Solvmanifolds, nilmanifolds, infra-nilmanifolds etc. also naturally arise in the theory of crystallographic groups, or more generally, discrete subgroups of Lie groups. Here geometry, algebra and number theory come "together". See Bill Goldman's survey article "W. M. Goldman: Two papers which changed my life: Milnor’s seminal work on flat manifolds and bundles.
Frontiers in complex dynamics, Princeton Math. Ser. 51 (2014), 679–703." Auslander's conjecture on solvmanifolds is still open, see Abels. Margulis and Soifer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me just give an example, where solvmanifolds are still studied today - see the comment above.
There is a famous open conjecture by L. Auslander:

**Conjecture (Auslander):** Every compact complete affine
manifold has virtually polycyclic fundamental group - in
this case, the manifold is finitely covered by an *affine solvmanifold* $G/\Gamma$, where $G$
is a (necessarily solvable) Lie group with a left-invariant complete
affine structure and $\Gamma\subset G$ is a lattice.

Abels, Margulis and Soifer have worked more than a decade on it. However, so far, only special cases have been solved.

Equivalently, every affine crystallographic group is virtually solvable. Or even differently, the fundamental group of a compact complete affinely-flat manifold is virtually solvable.

For a survey from a geometrical viewpoint see

*W. M. Goldman:* Two papers which changed my life: Milnor’s seminal work on flat manifolds and bundles. Frontiers in complex dynamics, Princeton Math. Ser. 51 (2014), 679–703.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the conjecture. A compact flat manifold is finitely covered by a torus which is a solvmanifold. What am I missing?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I edited the statement. Now it should make more sense. The formulation is taken from Goldman's article "Locally homogeneous geometric manifolds", page 9.